# Create pandas DataFrames in a function

Tags: python, pandas

How can I build a function that creates these dataframes?:

```
buy_orders_1h = pd.DataFrame(
{'Date_buy': buy_orders_date_1h,
 'Name_buy': buy_orders_name_1h
})

sell_orders_1h = pd.DataFrame(
{'Date_sell': sell_orders_date_1h,
 'Name_sell': sell_orders_name_1h
})
```

I have 10 dataframes like this I create very manually and everytime I want to add a new column I would have to do it in all of them which is time consuming. If I can build a function I would only have to do it once.

The differences between the two above function are of course one is for buy signals the other is for sell signals.

I guess the inputs to the function should be:

- _buy/_sell - for the Column name
- buy_ / sell_ - for the Column input

I'm thinking input to the function could be something like:

```py
def create_dfs(col, col_input,hour):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date' + col : col_input + "_orders_date_" + hour,
     'Name' + col : col_input + "_orders_name_" + hour
    }
    return df

buy_orders_1h = create_dfs("_buy", "buy_", "1h")
sell_orders_1h = create_dfs("_sell", "sell_", "1h")
```

Comment: Problem with my suggested function is col_input + ":_orders_date_" + hour would return as a string but it is actually a variable, how to fix this?

Comment: IIUC, you need to reference the global variables like `sell_orders_date_1h` by the string `'sell_orders_date_1h'`, in that case you could use `globals` dictionary for example you can do `'Date' + col : globals()[col_input + "_orders_date_" + hour]`

Comment: Updated my answer to address calling a variable using a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dataframe needs an index, so either you can manually pass an index, or enter your row values in list form:

```py
def create_dfs(col, col_input, hour):
    df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date' + col: [col_input + "_orders_date_" + hour],
     'Name' + col: [col_input + "_orders_name_" + hour]})
    return df

buy_orders_1h = create_dfs("_buy", "buy_", "1h")
sell_orders_1h = create_dfs("_sell", "sell_", "1h")
```

Edit: Updated due to new information:
To call a global variable using a string, enter `globals()` before the string in the following manner:

```py
'Date' + col: globals()[col_input + "_orders_date_" + hour]
```

Comment: Sorry, not sure how colons made their way there, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @doomdaam hope this answers your question. If so, please mark it as correct using the little check mark :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the output please to see if this is what you want. You first create two dictionaries, then depending on the `buy=True` condition, it either appends to the `buying_df` or to the `selling_df`. I created two sample lists of dates and column names, and iteratively appended to the desired dataframes. After creating the dicts, then `pandas.DataFrame` is created. You do not need to create it iteratively, rather once in the end when your dates and names have been collected into a dict.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd 
buying_df=defaultdict(list)
selling_df=defaultdict(list)


def add_column_to_df(date,name,buy=True):

    if buy:
        buying_df["Date_buy"].append(date)
        buying_df["Name_buy"].append(name)
    
    else:
        selling_df["Date_sell"].append(date)
        selling_df["Name_sell"].append(name)

dates=["1900","2000","2010"]
names=["Col_name1","Col_name2","Col_name3"]

for date, name in zip(dates,names):
    add_column_to_df(date,name)

#print(buying_df)

df=pd.DataFrame(buying_df)
print(df)
```